# Редактор исходного кода (текстовый редактор) с навигацией по проекту

Tags: c++, редактор

Существует ли в природе такой редактор текста (исходного кода), который позволял бы производить навигацию по всему проекту?

Редакторы на подобии Notepad++ или Atom очень удобные в части редактирования кода. Но существуют ли плагины для них, которые позволяли бы переходить по переменным или функциям по файлам проекта?

Comment: vim и emacs c плагинами вроде бы позволяют это делать

Comment: попробуй visual studio code. Вроде он без проблем переходит по функциям и переменным.

Comment: Попробуйте какую-нибудь IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле существует много способов решить данную задачу. И многие с них ограничиваются только фантазией программиста. Начнем с классики - vim.

## Классика - vim + ctags

В vim проблема автодополнения кода/навигации стояла давно и решение было придумано простое - ctags. Ctags - это маленькая программа, которая парсит сорцы и делает специальный tag файл, в котором хранится информация о переменных, функциях и тому подобном.

Плюсы решения:

- почти в любом линуксе "Из коробки".
- работает достаточно быстро
- можно гибко настроить (ниже)

Недостатки:

- нет парсинга "налету" (решается вызовом ctags по сохранению)
- нормально работает только с простыми языками - си и подобными, плюсы сильно хуже.
- автодоболнение "тупое", плохо привязано к контексту.

Хотя это и примитивное решение, но оно гибкое.  У меня был случай, когда нужно было делать навигацию по файлам шаблонов, движок которых был написан внутри компании и за ее приделами неизвестный. Несколько часов и был готовый перловый скрипт, который парсил (примитивно) шаблоны и формировал файл тегов. После этого вим запрыгал по них "нативненько". Базовые комбинации - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> - переход по тегу, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> - вернуться назад.

Если установить расширения [Ctrlp](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim), то можно будет искать по тегам с помощью CtrlPTag.

Еще, наличие файла тегов позволяет запускать так `vim -t <тег>` и вим найдет, где объявлен идентификатор и откроет нужный файл в нужном месте:)

[TagBar](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar) также может сделать жизнь чуточку лучше.

## vim + YouCompleteMe

Использовать плагин [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe). Данный плагин делает почти то, что многие ожидают - дополнение "на лету". На убунту ставится легко, на gentoo требовала плясок. Но работает очень интересно.

## vim+clang

Добавить в vimrc такую строку

```
let g:clang_library_path='/usr/lib/llvm..../libclang.so.1'
```

и поставить [плагин clang_complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete) (хотя у меня как то и без плагина работает...).

## Yavide

Упоминая вим, хочется сказать и [yavide](https://github.com/JBakamovic/yavide) - это уже хитро настроенный vim, который пытается выглядеть как полноценная ide.

## Visual studio code

Майкрософт взяла популярный редактор atom и попыталась исправить в нем "все фатальные недостатки" и сделала свой [редактор](https://code.visualstudio.com/).  Работает достаточно хорошо, если поставить следующие плагины ms-vscode.cpptools, ajshort.include-autocomplete (первый ставится обычно автоматом). Но мне не нравится как он показывает навигацию.

## Emacs

Также есть ещё эмакс, но я не большой любитель его, поэтому мало что смогу написать.

---

Все вышеприведенные способы хорошо заводятся в линукс. Visual studio code, не смотря на свое происхождение, хорошо справляется с задачами под линукс/мак, но плохо работал (похоже сейчас начали это исправлять) под виндой.

---

## Visual Studio Community

Под виндой хорошо поставить communiti версию студии. Она покроет много задач и самое главное - бесплатна.

## Qt Creator

Вторая неплохая IDE как не странно - QtCreator. Под линуксом я перешел на него, отказавшись от Visual studio code (но для мелких проектов все равно использую вим:) ). Последнее время QtCreator достаточно хорошо развивается, так что покроет базовые вещи легко.

## Разное

Есть ещё много других IDE - CodeBlock, CodeLite, Eclipse, но как то они не в ту сторону движутся.

## Clion

Отдельно хочется упомянуть [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/). Если продукты Jetbrains знакомы, то может оказаться удобным. Но у него есть три больших недостатка - сильно платный, тормознутый (впрочем, как и остальные продукты, которые запускаются на jvm) и он написан не на с/с++ - это как проектировать спорткары, но при этом ездить на запорожцах/москвичах.

## Бонус - Juci++

Недавно увидел новую чудную маленькую ide - [juci++](https://github.com/cppit/jucipp).  Работает приятно, настраивается модно с помощью json файла, который применяется "на лету". Буквально за пол часа удалось почти все настроить под себя.

## а может все таки Notepad++?

Для него есть даже большая инструкция по настройке [на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/220081/). Попытки адаптировать Clang под него [я видел](https://sourceforge.net/p/npp-plugins/discussion/672146/thread/e02994b0/), но не пробовал. Также есть поддержка [Ctags](http://gtagfornplus.sourceforge.net/) или [этот](https://github.com/pnedev/nppgtags).

Comment: KDevelop - довольно удобен.

Comment: Возможно, но у меня нет желания его сейчас тестировать - что бы его поставить, нужно много-много kde зависимостей.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за такой развёрнутый ответ